# Else Portion of Code keeps timing out

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a code to check the connection between access and sql server upon opening the form. If there is a connection a message box pops up and says so. If not there is supposed to be a message box indicating there is no connection. Instead I get the error:

```
Run Time Error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]Specified SQL Server Not Found
```

Which is not what I am wanting it to do, is it something in my coding or is there no way to get this to work?

```
Public Sub AutoExec()
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim localrst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim remoterst As New ADODB.Recordset

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
cnn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=DB; Initial Catalog=HRLearnDev;" _
& "User Id=ID; Password=PW;"

If cnn.State = adStateOpen Then

MsgBox ("You have an established connection with the L&TD SQL Server Database.")
Else
MsgBox ("Cannot connect to remote server. Data will be stored locally  to CDData Table until application is opened again.")

End If

cnn.Close



End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In situations like these, you typically want to use an `On Error GoTo` construct - then send the code to your error handler if an error occurs (you can test to make sure the error number is what you expect with `Err.Num`).

However, in your case it may be even easier to use `On Error Resume Next`. This tells the interpreter "If an error occurs, go to the next line. I will figure out what went wrong and deal with it."

You usually do this when you have a single function call that either produces an error or a sensible value. I often do something like this:

```
On Error Resume Next
returnValue = -1
returnValue = functionThatReturnsPositiveValue()
If returnValue < 0 Then
  MsgBox "oops - the function failed!"
Else
  ' <<<< do whatever needs doing >>>>
End If
```

In your case that's almost exactly what you would do.  Complete example:

```
Public Sub AutoExec()
  Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
  Dim localrst As New ADODB.Recordset
  Dim remoterst As New ADODB.Recordset

  On Error Resume Next          ' <<<<<< add this line so an error doesn't stop the code
  Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
  cnn.State = 0 ' <<<<< not sure if you need something like this, or if the New command
                        already set it to some sensible value other than "adStateOpen"

  cnn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=DB; Initial Catalog=HRLearnDev;" _
    & "User Id=ID; Password=PW;"

  If cnn.State = adStateOpen Then        ' <<<<<< this will only be true if no error occurred
    MsgBox ("You have an established connection with the L&TD SQL Server Database.")
  Else
    MsgBox ("Cannot connect to remote server. Data will be stored locally  to CDData Table until application is opened again.")
  End If
  On Error GoTo 0     ' <<<<<<<< turn off error handling - we have passed the "tricky" spot.

'  <<<<<< lots more code goes here >>>>>>

  If cnn.State = adStateOpen Then cnn.Close  ' <<<<<<<< only close connection if it was open!!

End Sub
```

Comment: How would this look? I am a novice when it comes to this stuff

Comment: That worked beautifully, the second window now pops up. But when I click ok I get the: Run Time Error 3704. Operation is Not Allowed when object is closed. And it highlights the cnn.close portion of the code.

Comment: Of course it will. You can't close a connection you didn't open. I modified the last line to show how that is done. You might also look at `Exit Function` as a way to "escape early" from a function (when the database doesn't open you might want to go somewhere else altogether - I don't know how the rest of your code is structured...)